# Monitor a program and restart it on crash

Tags: c++, winapi, signals

I have a program which crashs sometimes. On such occasion my program should restart itself. But while killing it through Task Manager it should end.
I have create Monitor program which monitors actual program and restart it on crash.
I have do this job using signals that are sent the actual program to terminate it.
I am using Windows OS.
**That is I need to intercept the signal sent to actual program in my monitor program**

Comment: Why not fix your program so that it doesn't crash?

Comment: What is your question? Why don't you fix your program?

Comment: My program rarely crashes say like time out cases,so on restarting it again makes it work fine. So at that cases my monitor program should restart it.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to intercept signals sent to program in my monitor program.

Comment: what you mean under "signals" ?

Comment: I mean SIGABRT, SIGINT,SIGFPE and so on

Comment: Your program should never crash.  You need to spend more time on fixing the problem, or at least finding out why the program crashes.

Comment: windows not use SIGABRT, SIGINT,SIGFPE

Comment: windows at all not have "signals" - this is from some other OS

Comment: I am able to signal handle of SIGINT in same program but I need to write signal handle function of a program in another program.

Comment: Wait for the process handle to be signaled. Simple enough. WaitForSingleObject.  But if you don't care about quality then what's the point. Why won't you fix your program.

Comment: I have tried that method. But I need know method that uses signals and events

Comment: No you don't. You wait for the process handle to be signaled. This is how it is done on Windows.

Comment: again - what is signals ?? no any signals in windows os

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - "But while killing it through Task Manager it should end." - so need not only wait on process handle, but determinate exit reason of process. are `GetExitCodeProcess` will be enough here ? for make out crash and terminate by task manager (exit code=1)

Comment: @RbMm I mean signals in [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_signal_handling.htm)

Comment: @Priya - this is **not for OS Windows**

Comment: @RbMm i have tried your method of getting exitcode, but while terminating through task manager the exitcode didnt turn out to be 1. It is just value same as crash exit code.

Comment: It is just value same as crash exit code - really ?

Comment: @RbMm What he means by task manager is that he wants to be able to terminate the process normally. The right way to do all of this is the procedure outlined in my answer.

Comment: You can somehow "emulate" the "signal" thingy: Create a new worker thread which will spawn the process and call `WaitForSingleObject()`. When this call returns (the process has ended or crashed), post a custom message to the thread that will be handling this situation (eg respawning the program) - or simply restart it in this "monitoring" thread. This won't affect the logic or setup of the rest of your application. And yes, sometimes applications (esp if a 3rd party is involved) do crash or hang, and your application/monitor can be specified to be able to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

A process monitor should do the following:

1. Create the main process, and thereby obtain a handle to that process.
2. Wait for that handle to become signaled, for instance with `WaitForSingleObject`, which indicates that the process has terminated.
3. Restart the process, obtaining a new process handle, and then go to 2.

You should arrange that the monitor program always creates the main process and that both are in a job object that is configured for child processes to be terminated when the parent terminates. Then when you wish to terminate the program, you simply terminate the monitor. The job object then ensures that the child program is also terminated.

If possible though, you should fix your program so that it does not crash.

Comment: But I should able to terminate the program without terminating the 'monitor' program.

Comment: Well, how would the monitor program know that this was intentional termination? If you really want to make sure that your process is always running then the procedure I outline is the way to go. Perhaps you need to have a little think about what you are trying to achieve. It seems to me that you've already decided on your solution (which doesn't work) and don't want to entertain anything else. In which case, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Let's ignore your question for a moment, and address the problem instead. You are looking for a way to restart your application on abnormal exit, but still retain the ability, to terminate the application (either through its GUI or Task Manager).

Windows offers [Application Recovery and Restart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948909.aspx) for this. It is the infrastructure built into the system, that allows you to register an application for restart in case of an unhandled exception (informally called *a crash*).

Answer (score 0):

of course you need fix your app, for it not crashed. only this is good solution. however formally you can do next (bad)

```
void Ep()
{
    // tag by * in begin of CommandLine
    PWSTR CommandLine = GetCommandLine();

    if (!CommandLine || *CommandLine != '*')
    {
        // monitor case

        WCHAR FileName[MAX_PATH];
        if (ULONG n = GetModuleFileName(0, FileName, RTL_NUMBER_OF(FileName)))
        {
            if (n < MAX_PATH)
            {
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
                PWSTR newCommandLine = (PWSTR)alloca((wcslen(CommandLine) + 2)*sizeof(WCHAR));
                *newCommandLine = '*';
                wcscpy(newCommandLine + 1, CommandLine);

                // monitor and restart self in loop
                BOOL bRestart;
                do 
                {
                    bRestart = FALSE;
                    if (CreateProcessW(FileName, newCommandLine, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                    {
                        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
                        ULONG exitcode;
                        bRestart = GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitcode);
                        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                        if (bRestart)
                        {
                            // 0xff - terminated by WerFault
                            // (int)exitcode < 0 - exception in process
                            bRestart = exitcode == 0xff || ((int)exitcode < 0);
                        }
                    }
                } while (bRestart);
            }
        }
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // main case

        wcscpy(CommandLine, CommandLine + 1);

        if (MessageBoxW(0, L"make crash ?", CommandLine, MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
        {
            __debugbreak();// simulate crash
        }
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
}
```